# Is there a way to send data, saved in a file from a raspberry sense hat, to an external source like my phone in live time?

Tags: python, google-sheets, raspberry-pi, export-to-csv

I have all the python code to save the time, pressure, temperature, and humidity to a CSV file that I just named Data file. I have a science fair coming up and I want to be able to set this raspberry pi in a room and have it send the time that the pressure temperature and humidity was taken. Right now I have it on an 80 second loop. My goal is to send the data put on the file and view it on my phone some how. I don't even know if this is possible but please give any suggestions!

Code to save time, pressure, temperature and humidity to a CSV file:

```
  from sense_hat import SenseHat
    import time
    sense=SenseHat()
    
    file = open("Datafile.csv","a")
    
    file.write("Time, Humidity, Temperature, Pressure")
    
    print ("Time, Humidity, Temperature, Pressure")
    
    for n in range(60 ):
        humidity = sense.get_humidity()
        humidity = round(humidity, 2)
        
        file.write(time.strftime('%X'))
        file.write(",") 
        file.write(str(humidity))
        file.write("/n")
    
        temperature = sense.get_temperature()
        temperature = round(temperature, 2)
        
    
        file.write(time.strftime('%X'))
        file.write(",") 
        file.write(str(temperature))
        file.write("/n")
        
        temperature = sense.get_temperature()
        temperature = round(temperature, 2)
        
        print (time.strftime('%X'),temperature)
        
        pressure = sense.get_pressure()
        pressure = round(pressure, 2)
        
        file.write(time.strftime('%X'))
        file.write(",") 
        file.write(str(pressure))
        file.write("\n")
        
        print (time.strftime('%X'),pressure)
        time.sleep(80)
    
    file.close()
```

Comment: Your problem is interesting but too broad: indeed, sharing data from a computer to a smartphone can be done in a lot of different ways. It is an entire project (for example: building a backend, automate sending of emails, ...) and it is too broad of a question for Stackoverflow. You could consider sending the data to a drive or via email for example :)

Answer (score 1):

For sure you can visualize the data you collect on your phone. You need to build a web application. The exact approach you should take will depend on how you would like to visualize the data.

The most complete solution would involve you connecting your Raspberry Pi to the internet via WiFi or Ethernet, and then having it send data to a server such as AWS. Then your phone would connect to the server, which will then display the data. This way you could see the data your Raspberry Pi is collecting from anywhere in the world.

However, this will take time to implement and perhaps you need something a little easier and quicker.

In this case, I would let your Raspberry Pi be the server itself. This way you would only be able to access your data when you are connected to the same network as the Raspberry Pi.

In order for your Raspberry Pi to be a server, you must use a webserver library such as Flask. Flask will allow you to display the file to a user whenever they navigate with their phone's browser to the IP address of the Raspberry Pi (again, as long as they are on the same network).

[Here](https://code-boxx.com/csv-table-python-flask/) is a guide on how to display a csv file with Flask.

You could either modify your current code to implement the Flask webserver, or have a separate Python script taking care of the Flask side of things and then have both of them running at the same time.

Hope this helped!